# D3 Dashboard Transitions Not Updating Certain Elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition

I am putting together a simple custom dashboard in d3 from examples that I have adapted from various sources online.  While I have made steady progress, I am stuck with a number of issues that may or may not be related, probably related to incorrect application of d3 transitions.

The issues that I am trying to resolve are as follows:
1. Pie Chart will not show anything at load time.  Chart will only load if the date field is changed.
2. Pie Chart legend doesn't update properly, switching from example 1 to example 2 leaves an empty box in the legend even though that example contains no instances of that class.
3. Labels do not update properly on the bar chart, and additionally the order of the bars does not correctly update either.  These are probably both tied to a problem with the transition.

Here is a fiddle demonstrating the behavior:

https://jsfiddle.net/Sledge/xo1s9dz9/6/

and here is my code:

```
var item_width = 40, item_height = 50;
var margin = {top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 75, left: 40},
    width = 700 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, height]);
var colorScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,10]).range(["white","#4169e1"]);

// Pie Chart parameters
var pieMargin = {top:25, right:25, bottom:25, left: 25},
    pieWidth = 350 - pieMargin.right - pieMargin.left, 
    pieHeight = 350 - pieMargin.top - pieMargin.bottom;
var outerRadius = Math.min(pieWidth, pieHeight) / 2,
        innerRadius = outerRadius * .50;
var pieColor = d3.scaleOrdinal(['#42b9f4','#3791f2','#374ff1','#25b22e','#107222']);
var legendRectSize = 18, legendSpacing = 4;
var enterAntiClockwise = {startAngle: Math.PI * 2, endAngle: Math.PI * 2};

// Top Item Parameters
var topItemMargin = {top:25, right:50, bottom: 25, left: 25};
var topItemWidth = 350 - topItemMargin.left - topItemMargin.right, 
      topItemHeight = 350 - topItemMargin.top - topItemMargin.bottom;
var topItemXScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, topItemWidth-5]);
var barHeight = 25, barSpacing = 5;


/* SVG */
var svgItemLayout = d3.select("#item_layout")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var svgPieChart = d3.select("#pie_chart")
    .append("svg") 
        .attr("width", pieWidth + pieMargin.left + pieMargin.right)
        .attr("height", pieHeight + pieMargin.top + pieMargin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (outerRadius + pieMargin.left) + "," + (outerRadius + pieMargin.top) + ")") ;

var svgTopItems = d3.select("#top_items")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", topItemWidth + topItemMargin.left + topItemMargin.right)
        .attr("height", topItemHeight + topItemMargin.top + topItemMargin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + topItemMargin.left + "," + topItemMargin.top + ")");


/* DRAW FUNCTIONS */
// a single function to draw 
function drawItemLayout(data){

  var x_offset = 5, y_offset = 5;

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.x_pos; }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.y_pos; }));

  var colorScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0,d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.sales; })])
    .range(["white","#4169e1"]);


  // create an update selection with a key function
  var g_sel = svgItemLayout
        .selectAll("g")
      .data(data, function(d){
        return d.item_name;
      });

  // get rid of those leaving the update
  g_sel
    .exit()
    .remove();

  // our entering g
  var g_ent = g_sel
    .enter()
    .append("g");

  // add our rects to our g
  g_ent.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "dot")
    .attr("width", item_width)
    .attr("height", item_height)
    .attr("rx", 3)
    .attr("ry", 3)
    //.style("fill", function(d){ return colorScale(d.sales); })
    .style("fill-opacity", 0.8);

  // add our text to our g
  g_ent.append("text")
    .attr("font-size", 10)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("fill", "black")
    .attr("dx", item_width/2)
    .attr("dy", item_height/2)
    .text(function(d){ return d.item_name; });

  // UPDATE + ENTER selection
  g_sel = g_ent
    .merge(g_sel);

/*  $('rect').tipsy({ 
      gravity: 'w', 
      html: true, 
      title: function() {
        var d = this.__data__;
        return 'Sales: '+d.sales; 
      }
    });*/

  // move them into position with transition
  g_sel
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .delay(function(d, i) { return i *40; })
    .attr("transform", function(d){
      return "translate(" + (x(d.x_pos) + x_offset)  + "," + (y(d.y_pos) + y_offset) + ")";
    })
    .style("fill", function(d){ return colorScale(d.sales); });

}

function drawPieChart(data) {

    var cf = crossfilter(data);
    var salesDimension = cf.dimension(function(d){ return d.sales; });
    var categoryDimension = cf.dimension(function(d){ return d.category_name; });
    var categoryGroup = categoryDimension.group();

    function reduceInitial(p, v) {
        return {
            sales : 0,
            count : 0
        };
    }

    function reduceAdd(p, v) {
        p.sales = p.sales + v.sales;
        p.count = p.count + 1;
        return p;
    }

    function reduceRemove(p, v) {
        p.sales = p.sales - v.sales;
        p.count = p.count - 1;
        return p;
    }

    categoryAggregated = categoryGroup.reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial).all();

    console.log(categoryAggregated);

    var arc = d3.arc()
      .innerRadius(innerRadius)
      .outerRadius(outerRadius);

    var pie = d3.pie()
    .value(function(d) { return d.value.sales; })
    .sort(null);

  var path = svgPieChart.selectAll('path')
      .data(pie(categoryAggregated), function(d){ return d.data.key; });

    path
      .enter()
      .append('path')
      .attr('d', arc(enterAntiClockwise))
      .attr('fill', function(d, i) { return pieColor(i); })
      .each(function(d){ this._current = d; }); // store the initial values

    path.exit()
        .transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attrTween('d', arcTweenOut)
        .remove();

    path
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attrTween('d', arcTween);


    // remove old legend:
    svgPieChart.selectAll(".legend").remove();

    // Add a legend:
    var legend = svgPieChart.selectAll('.legend')
      .data(pieColor.domain())
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'legend')
      .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
        var height = legendRectSize + legendSpacing;
        var offset =  height * pieColor.domain().length / 2;
        var horz = -3 * legendRectSize;
        var vert = i * height - offset;
        return 'translate(' + horz + ',' + vert + ')';
      });

    legend.append('rect')
      .attr('width', legendRectSize)
      .attr('height', legendRectSize)
      .style('fill', pieColor)
      .style('stroke', pieColor);

    legend.append('text')
      .attr('x', legendRectSize + legendSpacing)
      .attr('y', legendRectSize - legendSpacing)
        .text(function(d) { console.log(categoryAggregated[d].key);return categoryAggregated[d].key; }); 

    // TRANSITION FUNCTIONS
    // Then, interpolate from _current to the new angles.
    // During the transition, _current is updated in-place by d3.interpolate.
    function arcTween(a) {
      var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
      this._current = i(0);
      return function(t) {
      return arc(i(t));
      };
    }
    // Interpolate exiting arcs start and end angles to Math.PI * 2
    // so that they 'exit' at the end of the data
    function arcTweenOut(a) {
      var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, {startAngle: Math.PI * 2, endAngle: Math.PI * 2, value: 0});
      this._current = i(0);
      return function (t) {
        return arc(i(t));
      };
    }

}


function drawTopItems (data) {

    var cf = crossfilter(data);
    var salesDimension = cf.dimension(function(d){ return d.sales; });

    topData = salesDimension.top(10);

    topItemXScale
        .domain([0,d3.max(topData, function(d) { return d.sales; })]);

    var g_sel = svgTopItems.selectAll("g")
        .data(topData, function(d){ return d.item_name; });

    g_sel.exit().remove();

    var g_ent = g_sel
        .enter()
        .append("g");

    // UPDATE + ENTER selection
  g_sel = g_ent
    .merge(g_sel);

    g_ent
        .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "dot")   
    .attr("width", function(d){ return topItemXScale(d.sales); })
    .attr("height", barHeight)
    .style("fill","#3791f2")
    .style("fill-opacity", 0.8);

  // add our text to our g
  var labelTxt = g_ent
    .append("text")
    .attr("font-size", 12)
    .attr("text-anchor", "left")
    .attr("fill", "black")
    .attr("dy", barHeight/2)
    .text(function(d){ return d.item_name; })
    .attr("transform", function(d, i){
      return "translate("+(topItemWidth)+", 0)";
    });

  var valueTxt = g_ent
    .append("text")
    .attr("font-size", 14)
    .attr("text-anchor", "left")
    .attr("fill", "white")
    .attr("dy", 2*barHeight/3)
    .text(function(d){ return d.sales; })
    .attr("transform", function(d, i){
      return "translate("+(0.9*topItemXScale(d.sales))+", 0)";
    });

  g_sel
    .transition()
    .duration(1200)
    .delay(function(d, i) { return i *40; })
    .attr("transform", function(d, i){
      return "translate(0, "+(i*(barHeight + barSpacing))+")";
    })
    .attr("width", function(d){ return topItemXScale(d.sales); });

}

/* UTILITY FUNCTIONS */
function castData(data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.item_name = d.item;
    d.x_pos = +d.x_pos;
    d.y_pos = +d.y_pos;
    d.fixture_id = +d.fixture_id;
    d.db_id = +d.db_id;
    d.campaign_id = +d.campaign_id;
    d.sales = +d.sum_units_sold;
    d.category_name = d.category;
  });

    return data;
}

function filterData(data, campaignId, fixtureId) {

    data = castData(data);

    data = data.filter( function(d){ 
        return (d.campaign_id === campaignId  && d.fixture_id === fixtureId);
    });

    return data;

}


/* MAIN */
    var data = d3.csvParse( d3.select("pre#data").text());
    // pre-filter data
  data = filterData(data, 1550, 10987018);

  drawItemLayout(data);
  drawPieChart(data);
  drawTopItems(data);


/* UPDATE DATA */
function updateData(campaignId, fixtureId) {

  var data = d3.csvParse( d3.select("pre#data").text());

  // pre-filter data
  data = filterData(data, campaignId, fixtureId);

  drawItemLayout(data);
  drawPieChart(data);
  drawTopItems(data);

}


/* GET SELECTION */
$("#select_date_div").change(function(){
    var date = $("#select_date_div :selected").val();
    var fixtureId = $("#select_fixture_div :selected").val();
    date = +date;
    fixtureId = +fixtureId;
    updateData(date, fixtureId);
});

$("#select_fixture_div").change(function(){
    var date = $("#select_date_div :selected").val();
    var fixtureId = $("#select_fixture_div :selected").val();
    date = +date;
    fixtureId = +fixtureId;
    updateData(date, fixtureId);
});
```

I feel like I understand how to implement transitions for the simple examples I have found online.  For an example like this where I am attempting to update multiple elements of a given `<g>`, there is something that I don't quite get.

I would love to have some feedback both in terms of how to fix these specific issues, as well as conceptually what am I missing about how these transitions work, particularly when multiple aspects of the chart are changing.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: Issues #1 & #3 are solved.  I am still having an issue where the legend just overwrites what's already on the graph, so each time you select a parameter you get a mess of text and rectangle piling up.  I am thinking about submitting as a separate question since this one was kind of garbled with issues.

Comment: I have an updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lqnoupk8/) where it solves issues 1 and 2. You should also think in terms of update, enter and exit. You update the parameters on update, For enter, you need to add the elements and add the parameters. Finally you need to remove the elements on exit. You should also used the original data on the legend rectangles and text. In that way it is easy follow the update,enter and exit semantics when data gets updated.

Comment: I fixed all the issues.  I would post my own answer to this question but there is not a lot of interest here apparently.  Most of the problems were due to incorrectly selecting groups that contained elements other than the ones I wanted to operate on.  I read through https://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/ which helped a ton.  Adding classes to groups was the way out.